# Tkinter class module reference exception

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm having some trouble calling a module(updateUI) within a class (Eventsim).

The line Sim = EventSim() throws an exception because it's missing an argument (parent). I can't figure out how to fix this / reference the parent object.

This is my first attempt wit Tkinter and my python knowledge is also rather limited (for now).

```
from Tkinter import *


class EventSim(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

    def updateUI(self,IP_Address,Port_Number,Events_Directory):

        self.parent.title('ECP Event Simulator')
        self.parent.resizable(0, 0)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)
        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=X)
        frame3 = Frame(self)
        frame3.pack(fill=X)
        frame4 = Frame(self)
        frame4.pack(fill=X)
        frame5 = Frame(self)
        frame5.pack(fill=X)
        frame6 = Frame(self)
        frame6.pack(fill=X,pady=(10,30))
        frame7 = Frame(self)
        frame7.pack(fill=X)
        frame8 = Frame(self)
        frame8.pack(fill=X,pady=(10,0))


        Main_Label = Label(frame1,text='ECP EventSim')
        Main_Label.pack(side=LEFT,padx=100)

        IP_Label = Label(frame2,text='IP Address:')
        IP_Label.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
        Port_Label = Label(frame2,text='Port:')
        Port_Label.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=70)

        IP_Text = Entry(frame3)
        IP_Text.pack(fill=X,side=LEFT,padx=10)
        IP_Text = Entry(frame3)
        IP_Text.pack(fill=X,side=RIGHT,padx=10)

        Dir_Label = Label(frame4,text='Events Directory:')
        Dir_Label.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
        Dir_Text = Entry(frame5)
        Dir_Text.pack(fill=X,side=LEFT,padx=10,expand=True)

        Save_Button = Button(frame6,text='Save Config')
        Save_Button.pack(fill=X,side=LEFT,padx=10,expand=True)
        Con_Button = Button(frame7,text='Connect')
        Con_Button.pack(fill=X,side=LEFT,padx=10,expand=True)
        Send_Button = Button(frame8,text='Start Sending Events')
        Send_Button.pack(fill=X,side=LEFT,padx=10,expand=True)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300+750+300")
    app = EventSim(root)
    root.mainloop()


Sim = EventSim()
Sim.updateUI('1','1','1')
main()
```

Comment: look at your own code: you have one place where you pass a parent and one place that you don't. Remove the one that doesn't pass a parent, it seems redundant.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the updateUI method. If so, that's my mistake. I was experimenting and passing parent was not part of the original code. I'll take it out, however, it does not fix the problem as the exception gets thrown before that module is called.

Comment: You're correct. According to the code I posted they're not being used, however they will be in the future. I just forgot to take the parameters out before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent` should be `root`. So, replacing:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300+750+300")
    app = EventSim(root)
    root.mainloop()


Sim = EventSim()
Sim.updateUI('1','1','1')
main()
```

with:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+750+300")
Sim = EventSim(root)
Sim.updateUI('1','1','1')
root.mainloop()
```

brings up the desired window. The `updateUI` method requires work to populate the entry fields but you can remove its `parent` parameter since you already have the `parent` instance variable.

Comment: That does work. Thank you. It makes sense now that I see it.  
Can you elaborate on "some work" as far as the updateUI goes? Just a general hint? I'm trying to learn so I'm not looking for an exact answer, but maybe just a pointer in the right direction. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, the `IP_Address`, `Port_Number`, and `Events_Directory` parameters to `updateUI` are not being used. I assume the entry fields should be populated with their values based on the method name.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Sim = EventSim()` and move `Sim.updateUI('1','1','1')` to `main`:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300+750+300")
    app = EventSim(root)
    app.updateUI('1','1','1')
    root.mainloop()

main()
```